# Circuit design help: producing ultrasonic sound waves

Tags: circuit-design, sound, ultrasound

I'm working to develop a device that produces ultrasonic sound waves (40 kHz) to scare away animals. We used the circuit schematic shown below in our prototype with [this transducer](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/cusa-t80-18-2400-th.pdf) and a 12 V battery pack.

I was wondering if you guys have any better ideas or ways we can produce these waves at a higher volume. Also, if you know of any way we can test our prototype; I'm not sure how we can actually tell if we're producing these waves.

[image: Previous Circuit used]

Comment: It is complicated to make device to scary all animals. They have different hearing abilities and 40kHz most of them will not be affected. For bigger voltage solitude you need to drive transmitter via H- bridge.

Comment: Why do you have the 2N2222 transistor and a low current (12V/2.2k= 5.5mA) 2.2k resistor driving the high capacitance of the piezo transducer when the output of the 555 can produce a much higher current of 200mA?

Comment: look for a horn tweeter that goes to 40Khz

Answer (score 1):

Olimex has a nice [Ultra Sound Levitation Kit](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Soldering-Kits/Ultra-Sound-Levitation/open-source-hardware) which you might find useful, either to buy or to study (it's open source).  Though powered by 5V USB, they cleverly use/abuse a MAX232 to drive a pair of piezos at rs232 voltage levels.

In the kit, an arduino sketch on the microcontroller generates a square wave, with a pot so you can tune for resonance.  If you wanted a different sound that might be more useful for animal scaring (say, a chirp or a frequency sweep), you could program the microcontroller to generate that